# Creating a simple program in C++ for windows. How to build GUI

Tags: .net, c++, wysiwyg

For a school project, we need to create a fairly simple app using C++ and .NET framework. I only know C++, but we need to produce a working executable file for the project. The prof said we can use WYSIWYG editors for the GUI, but i can't seem to find one in Visual C++. I wanted to code with Visual C++ since i want to learn about Visual Studio.

Is there a way I can use a GUI builder application for C++ and somehow connect it with my project in Visual C++?

I'm very new to .NET and have spent the past 3 hours reading about .NET and the developer tools and what not, and i'm kinda lost..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1) Download `Visual C++ 2008 Express` for free [here](http://www.microsoft.com/express/Downloads/#2008-Visual-CPP)

2) Go to `File->New->Windows Form Application`.

Done! You got the WYSIWYG editors for the GUI.

Hope it helps
  Max

Comment: Remember to use CTRL-SHIFT-B to build.

Comment: thanks, now i created the existing code i have for the project with File->New->win32 Project, but the Windows Form Application is under CLR
Should i recreate the application differently somehow or just use the Windows Forms Application for the whole project?

Comment: This is the best route. If you are looking for a cross platform toolkit look into GTK.

Comment: You have to create a Windows Form Application to make a .NET Application. You should create a new project. The win32 project doesn't fits your needs.

Comment: yeah i've playing around with it, i'm gonna have to do everything under Forms application.. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

I use wxWidgets and wxFrameBuilder for my GUI.  It does not require ".NET", but that's what I like about it. :-)

wxFrameBuilder is a tool that helps you create the GUI layout.

Comment: do i need to use their SDK, or can i just produce the skeleton code for the gui, and connect it all together within Visual C++?

Comment: @Wonder, but you are saying "we need to create a fairly simple app using C++ and .NET framework", so it means you are expected to use .NET Framework and C++ (I understand it is Managed C++ or C++/CLI). If these are requirements, then keep in mind that Qt is useless for your project.  Qt is a separate GUI toolkit (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qt_%28toolkit%29), though it is usable with Visual Studio IDE and Visual C++ compiler, but WYSIWYG design of GUI elements will not be available form Visual Studio IDE. You need to use dedicated tools Qt Designer / Qt Creator.